# Obtain $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left\{\left|1-X_{n}\right|\right\},$ if it exists for $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}.. RVs$ and under conditions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

$X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots .$ are nonnegative $\mathrm{RVs}$, such that $ \boldsymbol{X}_{n} \stackrel{\text { a.s. }}{\rightarrow} \mathbf{0}$ (a.s stands for almost sure convergence) and $\lim\limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left\{\boldsymbol{X}_{\boldsymbol{n}}\right\}=\mathbf{2}$, where $\mathbb{E}$ stands for expectation of a random variable RV.
I want to obtain
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left\{\left|1-X_{n}\right|\right\}, \text { if it exists }
$$
There is no independence supposed here, I tried to go from the a.s convergence definition or simply by performing upper-bounds but I still fail and can't seem to see the use of the expectation convergence to $2$ which is obviously important here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $M\geq 1$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[|1-X_n|]=\mathbb{E}[(X_n -1)1_{X_n\geq M}]+\mathbb{E}[|1-X_n| 1_{|X_n|\leq M}]
$$
Now, for uniformly bounded variables, a.s. convergence implies $L^1$-convergence by the dominated convergence theorem. Thus,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[|1-X_n| 1_{|X_n|\leq M}]=1
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X_n-1)1_{X_n\geq M}]=\mathbb{E}[X_n 1_{X_n\geq M}]-\mathbb{P}[X_n\geq M]
$$
since $X_n\to 0$ a.s., we also have $X_n\to 0$ in probability and hence,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\mathbb{E}[X_n 1_{X_n \geq M}]-\mathbb{P}[X_n\geq M]\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n 1_{X_n\geq M}]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n]-\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n1_{X_n<M}]=2.
$$

Hence,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[|1-X_n|]=3.
$$

Comment: Note that $\mathbb E[(X_n-1)1_{X_n\ge M}] = \mathbb E[X_n1_{X_n\ge M}] - \mathbb P[X_n\ge M]$, rather than what you have written. To conclude $\mathbb E[X_n1_{X_n\ge M}] \to 2$, you will likely need some argument that takes $M\to\infty$.

Comment: @Jason That's a typo, sure, but if you read the next displayed equation, it should be clear to you that the result stands. No need to play around with $M$ at all.

Comment: Right, of course. Apologies.

Comment: All good, mate.